# Rust all write to file methods give 'method not found in std::io::BufReader<std::fs::File>'

Tags: file, rust

I've been following tutorials, accepted answers, and the docs. They never worked for me since the beginning of learning, and now I'm stuck at it again.
Imports:

```
  use std::io::prelude::*;
  use std::fs::{File, OpenOptions};
  use std::io::Read;
  use std::io::BufReader;
  use std::io::BufRead;
  use std::io::Write;
```

Code:

```
  let mut file_help = OpenOptions::new().append(true).create_new(true).open("n.txt").expect(".");
  let mut file_help = BufReader::new(file_help);
```

Loop for vec:

```
for i in d_call {file_help.write(format!("{}\n",i))};
```

In-loop variants that are giving out same error`` method not found in `std::io::BufReader<std::fs::File> ``:

```
file_help.write_all(format!("{}\n",i))

write!(file_help, "{}\n",i)

file_help.write(format!("{}\n",i.to_string()))

writeln!(file_help, "{}", i.to_string())
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `write` found for struct `BufReader` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:21:19
   |
21 |         file_help.write(format!("{}\n", i.to_string()))
   |                   ^^^^^ method not found in `BufReader<File>`
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=05227e20159f82de2baabdb7bc0e0e8d).

Comment: Please always post the full error from `cargo check`.

Comment: The full error is more than that. It includes pointers to the source code, for example.

Comment: If you can create a reproducible example on the playground, this is the best.

Comment: I don't know what tutorial you followed, but you can write into `BufReader`.

Comment: here it is: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=05227e20159f82de2baabdb7bc0e0e8d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is actually quite simple. You are trying to write data to a `BufReader`. It can buffer file reads, but does not implement any write functionality. You likely want to use a `std::io::BufWriter` instead.